# jQuery Why on-change function doesn't work for 2 or more <radio>s?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, radio-button

This is the code I wrote - `.on("change", function(){}` and `.click(function(){}` for button to hide and show some objects.

But if I try it for more than one `<radio>`, it simply doesn't work.

Does anybody know why?

Code:

```
$('#radioid1').on("change", function(){
$("#button1").click(function(){
    $("#object1").hide();
    $("#object2").show();
    $("#button1").hide();
});

$('#radioid2').on("change", function(){
$("#button1").click(function(){
    $("#object1").hide();
    $("#object3").show();
    $("#button1").hide();
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work either :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .on() method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set of elements in the jQuery object, I change event click to .on() for bind event to element

```
$('#radioid1').on("change", function(){
    $("#button1").on('click', function(){
       $("#object1").hide();
       $("#object2").show();
       $("#button1").hide();
  });
});
$('#radioid2').on("change", function(){
    $("#button1").on('click',function(){
        $("#object1").hide();
        $("#object3").show();
        $("#button1").hide();
    });
 });
```